# Telegram bot analytics

Tags: telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

I have checked telegram bot api web but could not find analytics api for bot, is telegram provide
analytics api for bots, if yes any one have reference it will helps me a lot

Answer (score 0):

the Telegram API does not provide you with a way to get analytics. It is only an interface to operate the bot automatically.

However, there are services like this:
https://www.integromat.com/en/integrations/google-analytics/telegram

You can check it out and see if it fits your needs.
Whenever you build a database you can create metrics and analytics.

Answer (score 0):

To analyze statistics, Telegram Robot, you must save anyone who starts the robot in the database(json data base or mysql or etc). To do this, you can get the user id (it is easy to get the user id)